Backend Logs Show 'Token Undefined' Error
got this issue on "token undefined" in backend logs, working with expressjs, eventho in the frontend when i do inspect element and check Application cookies i find the token there
i don't get the data of the user, like after signing in the data should appear in the console, but something wrong with the token
